# How to Detect Android Device on Mac OS for Debugging?

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, adb

I am using **Mac Book Pro for Android app development**. But **Android studio** **not showing my Device (Nexus 6)** within device chooser dialog during app launch. I have gone through with following command on terminal (after setting my sdk tools path in HOME enviormental variable)

**$ adb update**

**$adb devices**

I have also installed **androidfiletransfer.dmg** but device is not showing on my **Mac Book**

Please help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you turned on the android debugging option on the device?

Comment: @AbdulWahab yes buddy. I always on debugging mode because I am using same device on windows platform and its working.

Comment: did you install android USB driver from sdk manager?

Comment: @AbdulWahab Yes. But when u try to install google usb driver from sdk manager it shows message that **"google usb driver not supported by Mac OS"**